# Convert the XML to JSON by preserving the data types without model in c#

Tags: c#, json, xml, xml-parsing, json.net

I am trying to convert an XML to JSON without changing the datatypes but it is always returning the string value. I have tried different ways to convert with proper data types.
Below is my source XML and expected JSON

```
<Employee >
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age>18</Age>
  <IsContractor>true</IsContractor>
  <Salary>5555.66</Salary>
</Employee>
```

**Expected Result**:

```
 "Employee": {
      "Name": "John",
      "Age": 18,
      "IsContractor": true,
      "Salary": 5555.66
    }
```

I have tried different ways but no luck

```
 string xml = @"<Employee>
                            <Name>John</Name>
                            <Age json:Type='Integer'>18</Age>
                            <IsContractor json:Type='Boolean'>true</IsContractor>
                            <Salary json:Type='Decimal'>5555.66</Salary>
                        </Employee>";
      
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

Also, I tried adding a datatype like this

```
          var xml = @"<Employee  xmlns:m=""urn:informatica:ae:xquery:json2xml:meta-data"">
                    <Name>John</Name>
                    <Age m:type=""xs:double"">18</Age>
                    <IsContractor m:type=""xs:boolean"">true</IsContractor>
                     </Employee>";
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        var result1 = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

But both ways all the values are converted to a string.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. If you have nested objects for example you just need to change an iteration algorithm

```
var xml = @"
<Employee >
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Age type='System.Int32'>18</Age>
  <IsContractor type='System.Boolean'>true</IsContractor>
  <Salary type='System.Double'>5555.66</Salary>
</Employee>";

    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDoc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, false);
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

    foreach (JObject element in jObj.Properties().First())
    {
        foreach (var prop in element.Properties())
        {
            if (prop.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
                prop.Value = ConvertToType((JObject)prop.Value);
        }
    }

    json = jObj.ToString();

public JValue ConvertToType(JObject jObj)
{
    var val = Convert.ChangeType(jObj["#text"], Type.GetType((string)jObj["@type"]));
    return new JValue(val);
}
```

output

```
{
  "Employee": {
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 18,
    "IsContractor": true,
    "Salary": 5555.66
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me also. Is this cause any performance issues if we parse large XML with multiple different datatypes

Answer (score -1):

You could use a workaround that utilizes Newtonsoft.Json to convert XML to JSON and then parse the JSON again to convert the string values to their appropriate data types.

```
string xml = @"<Employee>
                <Name>John</Name>
                <Age>18</Age>
                <IsContractor>true</IsContractor>
                <Salary>5555.66</Salary>
                </Employee>";

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);

// parse values to appropriate data types
json["Employee"]["Age"] = int.Parse(json["Employee"]["Age"].ToString());
json["Employee"]["IsContractor"] = bool.Parse(json["Employee"]["IsContractor"].ToString());
json["Employee"]["Salary"] = decimal.Parse(json["Employee"]["Salary"].ToString());

Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
```